# Spring Integration: CGLIB error during deployment

Tags: spring, aop, spring-integration, spring-aop, cglib

I am trying to implement a very simple integration flow, but can't figure out why I get an error during the deployment. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Xml Config:**

```
<gateway id="eventGateway"
         service-interface="com.acme.EventGateway"/>

<publish-subscribe-channel id="eventChannel"/>

<service-activator
        input-channel="eventChannel"
        ref="eventService"
        method="saveEvent"/>
```

**Interface:**

```
public interface EventGateway {
@Gateway(requestChannel = "eventChannel")
    public void saveEvent(Event event);
}
```

**Exception:**

```
Error creating bean with name 'eventGateway': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130
```

**EDIT:**
I also have a Java Configuration class with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` annotation.
When I remove `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` annotation the error goes away.

**EDIT2:**
I've tried annotating the interface with: 
`@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)` but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Strange - I can't reproduce it with a simple example; can you share more about the class that is annotated with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`? How is it pulled into the context etc. You have lots of proxies (at least 130), but that annotation should only affect classes annotated with `@Aspect`. My guess is some other BPP is proxying the gateway. First step would be to get DEBUG logs for org.springframework (assuming it's a framework BPP that's proxying). If that doesn't help, try whittling it down to a simple test case, and use a debugger to figure it out. I can help if you have a small test case.

Comment: I enabled the DEBUG level for the org.springframework but didn't find any additional info.